# How to install new Android Studio extensions to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, plugins, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible at the moment to add  the Android Studio extensions to a current IntelliJ IDEA installation?

Xavier Ducrohet and Tor Norbye mentioned in their talk, that Android Studio is an extension to the Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA and that it's not a fork. So it should be possible to add the extension.

Is there an easy way to do so and probably to revert?

They also mentioned in their talk, that Android Studio uses Gradle as default build system. This should break the builds of current modules. Is this correct?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30617524/3176433

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I finally found the corresponding statement by JetBrains: http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/

You can upgrade by hitting *help* -> *Checking for updates* and then choose *Early Access Program* as channel in the Update settings. You should receive a notification, that version 13 is available.

This EAP version contains almost all Android Studio features except the new Project Wizard and the App Engine Cloud Endpoints, but they will come soon. The reason for the delay is the Google IO, in the future new Android Studio and IntelliJ versions will be synced (mentioned in the comments of the blog post).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be at [androidstudio](https://code.google.com/p/androidstudio/) but the project is currently empty.

Comment: I doubt that project will be used. The official announced home for the code is https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/

Answer (score 0):

The installation page is here: [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

From what I understand in the download page & from what they said in the conference, it's a stand alone IDE based on the intelliJ, but i'm skeptical to whether one can get it as an extension to an already installed intelliJ IDEA.

About the build - in [Migrating from Eclipse page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) they explain how to generate Gradle build files for your projects in Eclipse and then import those projects to Android Studio. It's pretty simple and straight forward.