# Android Studio missing Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

What I'm trying to do is create an Android app that talks to my existing App Engine back end. I'm following the steps in http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html. I installed Android Studio 0.2.1 (I/O Preview, build AI-130.745757, built 18-July-2013) on a Mac.

The problem is that my Tools menu doesn't have Google Cloud Endpoints. My understanding from looking at this blog post: http://bradabrams.com/2013/06/google-io-2013-demo-android-studio-cloud-endpoints-synchronized-stopwatch-demo/, is that GCE is supposed to ship as part of Android Studio.

I have also read this answer: [How to install new Android Studio extensions to IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575143/how-to-install-new-android-studio-extensions-to-intellij-idea/16582442), but that concerns IntelliJ IDEA, rather than Android Studio itself.

Am I missing a step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the menu options used to be grayed out and the group still visible. But a recent change in how groups are displayed in the Tools menu just hides the "Google Cloud Tools' group if no options are enabled.  What you might need to do is create an Android project, click on the Android module in the project and then look at the tools menu.  It should appear there because the context allows some actions to be "enabled" so the menu group now appears.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. For some reason it doesn't appear initially, but does so after I add another module to the newly-created Android app project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the option was disabled, but I fixed by following these steps:

1. Go To File -> Settings
2. Select Plugins from the list
3. Search Google Cloud Tools for Android Studio
4. Select that option and make it enabled.
5. Restart Android Studio

and at last you should be able to see "Google Cloud Module"